# 16 bit char datatype from C# in PHP

Tags: c#, php, byte

I need to do this c# operation in php:

`char[] Offset = new char[4];
 Offset[0] = (char)(Offset[0] + 10);`

I know that it's because of **16 bit char** datatype. Is there any possibility to convert int to 16bit "char"?

Comment: php has no 16bit types. it has strings, integers, floats, arrays, and objects. integers are ALWAYS 32bit or 64bit, depending on the underlying environment.

Comment: so there is no possibility to convert it?

Comment: you can convert, just it won't be a 16bit int internally.

Comment: Yes, but will I get the same value as in the c# code?

Comment: if you write the php properly...

Comment: so long story short: it is possible to do this in php or am I wrong? Next question then is: How?

Comment: c# and php are both turing complete, so anything you do in one is possible in the other. HOW you do it will be different.

Comment: It would help if you show examples of input and the associated output that you expect.

Comment: The only thing I want to know is how to realize `(char)(Offset[0] + 10)` in php. Offset[0] is just a string value.